# What is the "peak to peak" analogy refrenced by numpy's .ptp function?

Tags: python, numpy

The np.ptp function returns the range between minimum and maximum values along a specified axis. The [numpy docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ptp.html) state that the "ptp" name is an acronym for "peak to peak". Can someone explain this analogy?

I would have thought this function would have been named "valley to peak".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common
[term](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/313269/peak-to-peak-vs-amplitude/313454)
in any electrical engineering text.

If you have a
[DC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_current)
voltage source referenced to some ground point,
it is easy to report the voltage
and predict how much a large-valued resistor would
heat up, that is, to predict dissipated power.

If you have an
[AC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_current)
voltage source, things are more complicated.
The simplest case tends to be a sinusoidal waveform,
which admits of analytic solutions for
[RMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square)
power dissipation.
But in general, an AC source might not be a perfect sinusoid.
It might be clipped, or have harmonics, or be approximately a square wave.
For all such cases we can accurately report the
[peak-to-peak](https://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/What-is-peak-to-peak-voltage.php)
voltage, even in an instance where an exotic waveform would make it a challenge
to predict what power would be dissipated by an attached load.